# Include a .so library using cmake

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I am not able to properly include a shared object library using cmake. I would greatly appreciate any insight.

My project structure:

```
include/
    in1/
        lots of .h and hpp files
    mylib/
        mylib.h
lib/
    several .so files
src/
    hello.cpp
```

My cmake files:

**/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(myproject)
cmake_policy(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    add_definitions("-DDEBUG_CHECKS")
endif()

find_path(JANSSON_INCLUDE_DIR jansson.h)
find_library(JANSSON_LIBRARY NAMES libjansson.a)
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(jansson DEFAULT_MSG JANSSON_LIBRARY JANSSON_INCLUDE_DIR)
mark_as_advanced(JANSSON_INCLUDE_DIR JANSSON_LIBRARY)
set(JANSSON_LIBRARIES ${JANSSON_LIBRARY})
set(JANSSON_INCLUDE_DIRS ${JANSSON_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_path(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR curl/curl.h)
find_library(CURL_LIBRARY NAMES libcurl.so)
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(curl DEFAULT_MSG CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
mark_as_advanced(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR CURL_LIBRARY)
set(CURL_LIBRARIES ${CURL_LIBRARY})
set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})

include_directories(
    ./include/)

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    link_directories(
        ./lib/)
else()
    link_directories(./lib/)
endif()

find_path(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR mylib/mylib.h)
find_library(MYLIB_LIBRARY NAMES mylib.so PATHS "lib/")
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(mylib DEFAULT_MSG MYLIB_LIBRARY MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
mark_as_advanced(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR MYLIB_LIBRARY)
set(MYLIB_LIBRARIES ${MYLIB_LIBRARY})
set(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_subdirectory (src)
```

**/src/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
add_executable            (hello hello.cpp)
target_link_libraries     (hello lib1 lib2 ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}  jansson mylib)
target_include_directories(hello PUBLIC ${DEP_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

The project builds, but when I run 'hello', it says "cannot find mylib.so, no such file or directory".
`ldd hello` returns that lib1 and lib2 are linked correctly, but mylib says "libmylib.so => not found".

I tried adding the block

```
 find_path(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR mylib/mylib.h)
    find_library(MYLIB_LIBRARY NAMES mylib.so PATHS "lib/")
    include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
    find_package_handle_standard_args(mylib DEFAULT_MSG MYLIB_LIBRARY MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
    mark_as_advanced(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR MYLIB_LIBRARY)
    set(MYLIB_LIBRARIES ${MYLIB_LIBRARY})
    set(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

and chacking cmake-gui showed that the variables contain the correct paths. However the `target_link_libraries` command still evidently does not find mylib.

Comment: "However the `target_link_libraries` command still evidently does not find mylib." - No, `target_link_libraries` actually finds your library; otherwise you would got the **linker error**. What you got is the error from the **runtime loader**. You could read [CMake RPATH Handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) wiki for more info about search mechanism used by runtime loader and a way how CMake could help.

Comment: Note, that as written in the wiki, by default CMake **automatically** adds to RPATH of the executable a directory for every library linked into it. So you shouldn't get an error when run the executable (and from `ldd`). It seems that your actual situation differs from the one you describe in the question post. E.g. the line `target_link_libraries     (lib1 lib2 ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}  jansson mylib)` is simply wrong: instead of `hello` executable it links `lib1` library (as the first argument). Also, `link_directories` is not needed when you use result of `find_library`.

Comment: Sorry, I copied that line incorrectly to here and realized that while laying on bed just now. It ir, in fact, target_link_libraries(hello lib1 lib2 ...)

Comment: @Tsyvarev 
Thank you for the reference to RPATH. I got it running by exporting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH then running hello. Now I just have to figure out how to automatically add it with cmake.

Comment: It's actually quite odd. The directories I added to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH were already in the runtime path as checked by `objdump -x hello`

Comment: Please, add **exact** output of `ldd` into the question post. Generally, when ask a question on Stack Overflow, instead of description like " it says that ..." it is better to provide an exact error message: There is high chance that you have missed something in that error message. And that missed information would help others to resolve your problem. (Would you truly understand the error message and all its aspects, then you would unlikely ask a question about that problem.)